# What is this game featured in the film ‘The Year of the Jellyfish’?

Tags: identify-this-game, identify-this-computer

In the 1984 movie *[The Year of the Jellyfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_of_the_Jellyfish)*, featuring Valerie Kaprisky, at  00:13:42 we see her play a video game on a console like an old Atari, Philips, etc)

Does someone know which console or which video game is this? Can you suggest some words for searching? I tried "80's spacecraft" "old atari fuel e f" but I fail.

[image: Screenshot of the game. The play area shows some kind of air- or spacecraft flying through a tunnel from an isometric perspective. At the top of the screen, apparently partially obscured, there appears to be some kind of score counter, which reads ‘ND00000’ and lives indicator, with two craft visible. At the bottom, there is a fuel indicator made of filled triangles pointing right, with the ‘full’ position labelled ‘F’ and the ‘empty’ position labelled ‘E’.]

Comment: I suggest asking in https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmyjoystick/

Comment: Given that you have a screenshot, this would have been [accepted on Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10197/) as well.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

That looks like the ColecoVision port of the arcade game [*Zaxxon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zaxxon).

[image]

In the scene you mentioned, the character definitely seems to be holding a ColecoVision controller with the joystick knob, side buttons and keypad. :)

[image]

Comment: Yea, that's definitely Zaxxon.  Going by the colors it could also be the TRS-80 (CoCo) or Dragon version.

Comment: No, it's not the CoCo version.  It has similar colors ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKAlk.jpg)) but the resolution is lower and the screen layout is different.

Answer (score 21):

The game is zaxxon (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zaxxon), an isometric shooter arcade game, developed and released by Sega in 1981.

[image: zaxxon image]

Comparing the image with the screenshots at https://www.mobygames.com/game/zaxxon/screenshots, the version from the film appear to be the coleco vision/adam or msx version.